# Recommended strategy for ASP.NET paging with large data, and optional sorting

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, paging

The project I am currently working requires retrieving/searching from large amount of data, the flow as below:-

1. Enter a keyword and search from about 500,000 members
2. Retrieve only top 6 members.
3. Allow sorting based on the member country or gender.
   Requirements: Using EF5.0

The data is currently displayed using a UserControl and DataBinded using Repeater, will be updated through an UpdatePanel with next, previous button, etc.It is preferably but not limited to using EF5.0, and I am opened to other options (e.g. SqlDataReader) and cast it back to the members object manually.

My current solution calling the Entities with skip by using the page number, i.e.

members = context.Members.Where( conditions here ).Skip(page number * size).Take(size);

My question will be: Is my strategy the industrial / common ways of doing it? Anyone with similar experience can share with me in terms of performance / optimization, is there any other better way to do so?

Comment: My question will be: Is my strategy the industrial / common ways of doing it? Anyone with similar experience can share with me in terms of performance / optimization, is there any other better way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

I got really good performance using a stored procedure, instead of a LINQ query.  This saves performance because of the query metadata generation/sql translation.  If you are returning a large result set, disabling change tracking is a good option too.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, does that mean using ROWNUMBER() and pass in the page number, size as the parameter?

Comment: Yes; I've used a table variable in SQL Server to store the keys of the records in the desired sort order, and return the subset using the given start index and page size.  It works very fast for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using database paging which uses ROWCOUNT check it here https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml and it gives really good performance with 200000 records including sorting and paging.